# How to break a sentence before specific character in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have in my table sentence:

```
Bill and Amount.
```

If the page is narrow, then the text looks like below:

```
Bill and
Amount
```

But I want to have word *and* in a new line like this:

```
Bill
and Amount
```

Is any way to do this without `<br>`, maybe using somehow custom CSS class?

Answer (score 3):

you can use non breakable space like this :

```html
Bill and&nbsp;Amount.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wbr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) (word break opportunity) and set `white-space: nowrap` on the element:

```css
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Bill<wbr> and Amount
</div>
```

*Note*: [IE 8+ does not support `<wbr>`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=wbr-element)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this would be to use a media query.

On small devices (less that 768px) 'and Amount' will break onto a new line. On larger devices (min-width 768px) it will display all on one line.

Obviously you could change the media query to be whatever you like.

https://jsfiddle.net/ywugo35o/

```
Bill <span>and Amount</span>

span {
    display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    span {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```